# How to make html image clickable inside a TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

I have the following text in a string in the resources file:

```
    <a href="mailto:mymail@mail.com">&lt;img src="mail_big" /&gt;</a>
```

It shows the image fine (I implemented ImageGetter) but it is not clickable. I have tried adding the Linkify thingy but I don't think it's meant for this case, and so it doesn't work. The setMovementMethod doesn't work either.

I have tried different combinations of the above:

```
    <a href="mailto:mymail@mail.com">&lt;img src="mail_big" /&gt;hello</a>
```

Here, even the "hello" part is not clickable (neither blue nor underlined).

```
    <a href="mailto:mymail@mail.com"><img src="mail_big" /></a>
```

This doesn't even show the image.

```
    &lt;a href="mailto:mymail@mail.com"&gt;&lt;img src="mail_big" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

If I just write the email, without the <a> tag it works perfectly, but I would like to use the image of an envelope that the user can click on. It's not possible to use an imagebutton because this text is in the middle of a string and so I can't split it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

I found a solution or rather found out how to do it correctly.

All I had to do was adding the setMovementMethod call before the call to setText in the TextView and ALSO, and **COMPLETELY NECESSARY**, remove the attribute "android:autoLink="all" from the layout. Apparently, parsing mails and urls in a string is mutually exclusive to interpreting the <a> link tags in a string. So one or the other but not both.

Finally my layout is just a TextView with nothing special, just width and height. The activity looks like this:

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.about_text);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_content), new ImageGetter(), null));
```

And the string is like this:

```
    <string name="about_content"><a href="mailto:nomail@mail.com"><img src="mail" /></a></string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you can try, using `android:clickable="true"` in the `view`.

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

in your xml for the TextView?

Also if you are trying to show images too you would very likely be better off using a WebView with it you will probably run into fewer hiccups while interrupting your HTML, and you should be able to style it to look the same as a TextView (if you want to)

Comment: I already tried this and it doesn't work. The thing is that I don't want to use a webview which feels like a heavy View, just to show a couple of emails in the About screen. I know it's not going to drain the device's resources but if it's possible to achieve this with a simple textview, I'd rather use it.

Comment: But TextViews weren't meant for housing Images... I think that is why it isn't working. Even though you managed to get it to show the image (I am a bit surprised that it works), it wasn't built to do so, and thus probably does not support all of the functionality of HTML which I think is why you can't get the link working. What if you just set a click listener on the TextView itself and use java code to launch an intent with the email address filled in? That seems like it would have nearly the same effect from the users perspective.

Comment: Well, I guess it's not meant to be. The thing is that I found that class, ImageGetter, which parses the img tags and thought that it would work better with TextViews. I guess that the html works fine in the textview but when you mix tags is when they go crazy (as in this case, 'img' inside 'a'). I can't do what you suggest because I have several emails in that textview so I wouldn't know (nor I don't want to calculate) where the user clicked. So in the end I did it in a different way :/  Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Solved it!! All I had to do was adding the setMovementMethod call before the call to setText in the TextView and ALSO, and COMPLETELY NECESSARY, remove the attribute "android:autoLink="all" from the layout. Apparently, parsing mails and urls in a string is mutually exclusive to interpreting the <a> link tags in a string. So one or the other but not both. I'll edit the question with the answer.

Comment: you should instead post the answer as an answer =). Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable and encouraged. After you post it it will make you wait a while but then you can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:mymail@mail.com\">This is a test link</a>"));
tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: This may work, but it doesn't make use of an image as the link content, which is the point of my question.

Comment: Please provide code for more context on what you are trying to do.